# How to print values from different fields combined?

Tags: shell, xquery, xidel

I'm using xidel and playing with web scraping (without templates for now).
I would like to get the title and price of a book and its price so they could be printed on one line for each entry:

title --> price

Based on an answer from this forum I can write:

```
./xidel -e 'doc("https://books.toscrape.com")//*[self::p[@class="price_color"] or self::h3]'
```

But how to write title and its price in one line?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
./xidel -e 'doc("https://books.toscrape.com")//article[@class = "product_pod"]!(.//h3 || "-->" || .//p[@class="price_color"])'
```

Comment: Sadly, the result for this command is the same as previous - first all of the titles and then all of the prices without line division

Comment: @SebastianM, I had assumed there is a single title and price. Please edit your question and show us the relevant HTML input structure so that we can see the relation between a "title" (represented as a `h3`) and a price (represented as the `p` with that class). To write an XPath expression selecting them both in context we need to know the structure of the HTML.

Comment: @SebastianM, I didn't notice the link in your code is real, check whether the edit helps, it seems there is an `article` container element so I have adapted the XPath expression.

Comment: I also found it after you told me to check the structure. I was trying to be too smart with the elements. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

> *Need to remember: Check the HTML structure first!*

If an HTML source is minified, or unreadably prettified (with lots of illogical indentations for instance), then for a better overview of all the element-nodes I'd recommend either of the following 2 commands:

```
$ xidel -s "https://books.toscrape.com" -e . --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
$ xidel -se 'serialize(doc("https://books.toscrape.com"),{"indent":true()})'
```

Then you'll quickly notice that the text-nodes you're after are direct children of the `<article>`-element-node and not descendants (`.//` not necessary). And since it's all (text-)nodes you're dealing with, you don't *really* need the `!` ([simple map operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-map-operator)):

```
$ xidel -s "https://books.toscrape.com" -e '
  //article/join((div/p[@class="price_color"],h3),";")
'
```

And personally, I only use [`x:join()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-join) / `string-join()` for combining 3 items or more. For 2 items I always do a simple string-concatenation:

```
$ xidel -s "https://books.toscrape.com" -e '
  //article/(div/p[@class="price_color"]||";"||h3)
'
$ xidel -s "https://books.toscrape.com" -e '
  //article/concat(div/p[@class="price_color"],";",h3)
'
$ xidel -s "https://books.toscrape.com" -e '
  //article/x"{div/p[@class="price_color"]};{h3}"
'
```

The last one is Xidel's own [extended-string-syntax](https://github.com/benibela/xidel/blob/master/readme.txt#L161-L165).

Answer (score 0):

I followed Martin advice and check the html structure and indeed there was an Article element in the code that should be used.
Martin solution works and the one I came to probably at the same time is:

```
./xidel -e 'doc("https://books.toscrape.com")//article ! string-join((.//p[@class="price_color"], .//h3), ";")'
```

Need to remember: Check the HTML structure first!

Issue solved